# local.sh wont persist on vmware esxi 7.0.3

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-server

I am running ESXi 7.0.3 ( free edition ) and I am trying to make some changes to /etc/rc.local.d/local.sh
After doing the changes I run /sbin/autobackup.sh manually to "technically" make the changes to persist.
Then I try to reboot and the changes just vanish. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, do you mean you're changing something inside a VM or are you trying to change something manually at the ESXi command line? If the latter then you need to learn more about ESXi, it's NOT linux, you almost never go in changing things like that - when you're at a command line it's simply a busybox-like environment, it's NOT linux so stop trying to do this and do things the way VMware intend.

If you're trying to do this inside a VM then this has nothing whatsoever to do with ESXi and must be a problem with the OS in the VM.